# Node.js post request keeps loading

Tags: node.js, express

when I try post request with an appropriate JSON postman keeps loading ...
in chrome console, it shows 404 error

that's the script to run the server localhost:3000/users
app.js

```
//Define express instance
const app = express();

//Define port number 
const port = 3000 ;

//Static folder for downloaded files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + "/public")));

//Route users Directory Setup
app.use("/users",users);


//Start server
app.listen(port , () => {
    console.log("Just started your server on port : " + port +" (localhost:3000)");
})
```

users.js 
register post the problem might be here couldn't figure it out searched every question on StackOverflow

```
//Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

  let newUser = new User ({
    name : req.body.name,
    email : req.body.email,
    username : req.body.username,
    password : req.body.password
  });

  User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      res.json({success: false, msg: 'Failed to register user'});
    } else {
      res.json({success: true, msg: 'User registered'});
    }
  });

});
```

user.js

```
// User Schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback) {
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}

}
```

Request

post localhost:3000/users/register

```
{
    "name" : "houssam",
    "username" : "houssam11",
    "email" : "houssam.bb0101@gmail.com",
    "password" : "ssssssss1111"
}
```

Comment: Your route is `router.post('/register')` but your making a request to `localhost:3000/users/register` note the "users"

Comment: its okay with "app.use("/users",users);" so i dont have to add users before / register that part is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation it shows the proper way to construct and save a document from your user model . https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html. Don't forget to add `return` before your res statement.

```
//Register
router.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

  let newUser = new User ({
    name : req.body.name,
    email : req.body.email,
    username : req.body.username,
    password : req.body.password
  });

  newUser.save((err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.json({success: false, msg: 'Failed to register user'});
    } 

    return res.json({success: true, msg: 'User registered'});

  });

});
```

Now if you want to hash the password before the user is saved you can use the pre-save hook https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html.

```
// User Schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
    var user = this;
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt){
        if(err) return next(err);

        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash){
            if(err) return next(err);

            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

}
```

Comment: I did as u suggested added the return / the pre-save hook and calling the save function but still facing the same problem which is ** the request keeps loading with an error on chrome console POST http://localhost:4200/users/register 404 (Not Found) **

Comment: @HoussamBoudiar use a tool like postman to make the post request not chrome.

Comment: yea postman doesn't show results it keeps loading when i send the post request

Comment: Then try at the very top to console log or return res.json to see if it returns anything at all